# self.slidingViewController is lost after pushViewController

Tags: ios, ecslidingviewcontroller

Here the deal.

Most of my views have a constant sliding menu.
Did it exactly like the tutorials -
`MenuViewController : UIViewController`
In addition I have the:
`InitialSlidingViewController : ECSlidingViewController`
And all the viewControllers are `UIViewController`

Some of the views are a dive in navigation so I want to use `pushViewController`
The thing is - that on some of these views, there is a button that takes me to a viewController that does need a sliding menu.
And the:
`self.slidingViewController`
is lost in the push.
What can I do?